# how to decrypt pgp file? What is best GUI tool for it?

Tags: gui, pgp

[image]

i have my s.jpg and t.jpg encrypted. 
Need to decode them with nazar*.pgp

how to do it?

Best GUI method.? Seahorse??
[image]

Comment: If you are using asymmetrical encryption, then I believe you have to add the secret key to your keyring before (But if you are using asymmetrical encryption, then the file should have been encrypted using your public key, and you should already have your secret key into your keyring from when you created the pair. If it is symmetrical encryption, then the .key file is nothing but a long passphrase

Answer (score 4):

A bit of info before. There are two forms of encryption, symmetrical and asymmetrical.

Symmetrical encryption uses the same key to both encrypt and decrypt a file. The key is usually a passphrase that you chose when you encrypted the file. The same passphrase is required to decrypt the file.

Asymmetrical encryption uses two different keys. One to encrypt a file a different one to decrypt it. Usually, the key to encrypt the file is public, and the file is encrypted with one recipient in mind, because it is the recipient's public key that will be used to encrypt the file. And then only the recipient, with his private key can decrypt the file.

[A simple video explaining it.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AQDCe585Lnc)

Since there are two ways of encrypting a file, there are also two ways of decrypting a file. When dealing with OpenPGP encryption on Linux the program used is usually GNU Privacy Guard, or GnuPG, invoked with the command `gpg`. GPG and PGP are both implementations of the same thing, a standard called OpenPGP, so usually both can handle files encrypted with either one.

### Decrypting a file encrypted with symmetrical encryption

Usually, all that is required is a simple `gpg FILE.gpg`. Once issued, you will be requested for a passphrase, and if correct, you will have a new `FILE`, on the same folder, which is the decrypted version of that file.

Sometimes, instead of remembering passwords, people might choose to symmetrically encrypt a file with a key instead. In this case, the key is still a passphrase/password, just one that you don't need to type. If you were given a key file together with the file, you might decrypt it with something like:

```
gpg --batch --passphrase-file PASS.key --output FILE --decrypt FILE.gpg
```

### Decrypting a file that uses asymmetrical encryption

If you read the bits I posted before and watched the video, you should know that there are two files used with asymmetrical encryption. Both a public key and a private key. The private key is, well, private. You do not want to share your private key, and nobody should be sending you their private key.

You should generate your own key pair, and share your public key with whom else might want to send you something. Likewise, you should share your public key with them, so that they can send encrypted files to you. Again, do not share your private key.

When dealing with asymmetrical keys and files, you have to add the keys to your keyring. When you generate your key pair, both of them should have been automatically added to it. And you want to add your friends public key to it so that you can encrypt files for them. If, for some reason, you were given a private key, you also have to add it to your key ring before you can decrypt files with it. To list which keys you already have stored you should use:

`gpg --list-keys` and `gpg --list-secret-keys`.

To import a key into your keyring you want to:

`gpg --import KEY`.

Once you have the private key in your keyring, all that you need to do is a simple `gpg FILE.pgp`. If you secured your private key with a passphrase, you will be prompted for it. Alternatively, if you wish to decrypt the file into a specific file, you can use:

`gpg --output MYFILE --decrypt FILE.gpg`

---

Now, dealing with your specific case. If you do not have the private keys necessary to decrypt it in the keyring, first you have to add them. My guess is that the private key is actually `sec.key`, and maybe the `nazar-2000.pgp` file. There is no real naming convention around it, so you'll have to either to test or use the `file` command to figure it out. As you might already know, Linux doesn't really care about file extensions. After that, decrypting them is as simple as I pointed out in the answer. That is, assuming they are using asymmetrical encryption.

As to GUI, I can't be of much help, maybe someone might chime in. I personally use and recommend the [Enigmail](https://enigmail.net/index.php/en/) extension with Thunderbird ([Addon link](https://addons.thunderbird.net/en-GB/thunderbird/addon/enigmail/?src=search)). The KDE program, [Kleopatra](https://kde.org/applications/utilities/kleopatra/), seems to be highly recommended to use on the system. Gnupg also have a few [recommended frontends](https://gnupg.org/software/frontends.html).